# Функции php и Базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Если соединение к бд открыто в теле основной программы, будут ли запросы к базе работать из функции, которая вызывается в теле программы?

**UPD:**

Будет работать? 
     <code>

```
  <? 
        соединение к бд;
        любой код;

        функция (блеать);

        function функция (блеать) {
        Запрос к бд ;
        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('db');
/* Может пригодится set names */
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
function foo($sql){
return mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
}

foo('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В php код программы выполняется построчно. То есть сначала нужно установить соединение, затем выполнять запросы.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: как я и говорил программа выполняется построчно. Запросы выполняться у Вас будут. И да.. Ниже верно сказано. Функция должна быть определена выше её использования.

Answer (score 0):

Запросы будут работать, но вот функцию объявить надо до использования.

Comment: до использования чего?

Comment: >>функция (плохое_слово);

у вас вызов идёт до её объявления.
Или это другая функция (не та, что объявляется сразу после этой строчки)?